# WordPress custom query-string not index by Google

Tags: wordpress, request.querystring

I have a WordPress site (www.AgingSafely.com) and on it I have built a plugin to show the “Details” about various Adult Family Homes (AFHs). All of the details are retrieved out of database table via a query-string (?asi_id=WA_Af_nnnnn) where the n’s are the AFH’s license number. I have created a “Site Map” page (https://www.agingsafely.com/asi-site-map/) that lists an overview and has links to the Details Page for each AFH, so that Google can find and link them. They are also listed in sitemap.xml.
Google isn’t indexing them, but is indexing the more normal pages on my site.

I figure that I need to change my URLs from https://www.agingsafely.com/adult-family-home/?asi_id=WA_Af_751252 to something like https://www.agingsafely.com/adult-family-home/AFH/751252 to make Google happy. To add a little more complication, The “Af” in the query string is for “Adult Family Home”. The plugin also handles “Boarding Homes” “Bf” and “Nursing Facilities” “Nf”.
How do I get the URL with the ?asi_id=WA_Af_751252 rewritten to AFH/75152
This appears to two parts: Change the links in the plugins to the /AFH/nnnn format which should be easy. Have some re-write rule that converts the new URL format back to a query string.
What is the best way to do this?
Does Google ignore query strings?

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning on a lot of people entering in that particular string in a google search? Possibly some will, but probably not. If you want people to be able to easily find your products/homes via google searches, yes I would change the links to something like https://www.agingsafely.com/adult-family-home/AFH/751252. Literally spell out as much as you can, unless a string is a popular part number that people search for or something like that.

Also, is your site integrated with google analytics and google search console? I would definitely do that if you haven't.